# Is it a good idea to config cPanel with a transactional email service?

Tags: cpanel, mailgun, exim, transactional-email

I have a dedicated web server based on cPanel. Recently I came across with some idea to set up my server with a transactional mail service, in potential Mailgun. There are many tutorials across the web explain how to integrate cPanel with Mailgun, something like this https://3sq.re/blog/2014/07/configure-exim-cpanel-use-mailgun/. 
However, I have been asking myself the following:

1) Is it better set up domain per domain or the whole server according to the tutorial above?
2) My server keeps receiving email, so we are going to have to platform dealing with email services?
3) What are the benefits and the drawbacks?

In addition, I have set up my server but just for test and it works.

I am not sure if I should keep this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the provided tutorial, You can setup the Mailgun server wide, it's not per domain setup. if you setup Mailgun on your server you will not face blacklisting issues with your server IP. But you will have to check Mailgun pricing chat as per your requirement.

Comment: Tks for answering! That was my question, which way is better, set up whole server as a default or domain per domain?

Comment: I will suggest you setup it for your whole server.